# Как организовать такой цикл?

Tags: c#, sql

Скажите у меня есть в бд http://s001.radikal.ru/i195/1201/66/8070bbdfa9f3.png (специально ссылку т.к разрешение большое, чтобы хорошо видно было), как мне сделать в C# такой цикл чтобы в элементе WebBrowser они постоянно просматривались друг за другом... и если добавить ещё один сайт в БД, то и он начнет просматриваться, я пробовал так:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 100500; i++)
{
 command.CommandText("SELECT Url FROM t_links WHERE ID='" + i + "'");
}
```

Но он просто открывает первый сайт и всё больше не переходит никуда.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, запрос, как мне кажется, лучше оформить так:

```
SELECT Url FROM t_links WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 100500
```

А во-вторых, как собственно вы меняете url-ы,чтобы они отображались в браузере? И что вы собственно собираетесь делать с открывшейся страницей? Если просматривать, то цикл не подойдёт.

Comment: Мне нужно просто вот браузер и есть 3 ссылки в БД, и чтобы они просто постоянно прокручивались, и все ничего с ними делать не буду, просто переходы.

Comment: тогда сначала загрузить все ссылки в рекордсет, потом по таймеру делать next и выводить текущую ссылку в браузер

Comment: А можно пример как это будет выглядеть?(желательно C#)

Answer (score 0):

Причин может быть много.

Попробуйте URL'ы сайтов куда-нибудь вывести, не открывая. Код выглядит странно.

Comment: странно! согласен

Comment: Я текущий URL, передаю в переменную типа string, но как сделать чтобы они друг друга сменяли?